# I can't install wordpress on a remote server

Tags: wordpress, ftp, installation, localhost

I've been trying to move my wordpress website from localhost to a remote server, I followed the instructions here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress and on many other tutorials, even a new empty wordpress site installation won't work!

I created the database, moved the files using FTP, verified the URLs everywhere...

the error i get is the following : when I open the website link.. or the installation link (http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/install.php) the navigator downloads a file instead of showing the installation page!

Any ideas what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your Remote Server has a PHP Interpreter installed? (like Apache?) 
It sounds like you are using an FTP Only Server - which is like a Storage Device.

Comment: thank's for your answer, I'll check with my webhost.

Comment: Actually that's the problem.. they have Apache but but didn't grant me all access rights as a user. Thank's a lot :)